# Hybrid property representing a shifted date in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I am attempting to create some SQLAlchemy models and am struggling with how to properly apply a `timedelta` to a particular column. The `timedelta` (specified in days) is stored as an integer in a separate table (`Shifts`) and is potentially different for each record in my `Exam` table.

If I use a `hybrid_property`, I am able compute the property with the shifted date

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy


class Exam(Base):
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'database.dbo'}

    PT_ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    # Unshifted date
    START_DTTM = Column(DateTime)

    shiftlink = relationship('Shifts', uselist=False)

    # I want the DATE_ADD attribute to be easily accessible here
    DATE_ADD = association_proxy('shiftlink', 'DATE_ADD')

    @hybrid_property
    def START_SHIFTED(self):
        return self.START_DTTM + timedelta(days=self.DATE_ADD)


class Shifts(Base):
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'otherdb.dbo'}

    PT_ID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Exam.PT_ID))

    # Date shift in days (stored as an integer)
    DATE_ADD = Column(Integer)
```

However, I would like to be able to filter my query based upon this shifted date.

If I try to do this as it's written above, I get the following error

> TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'AssociationProxy'

In an attempt to fix this, I tried to define the following `expression` for the hybrid property

```
@START_SHIFTED.expression
def START_SHIFTED(cls):
    return func.dateadd(text('day'), cls.DATE_ADD, cls.START_DTTM)
```

When I attempt to filter using this, the actual query looks *kind of* correct except that there is no `JOIN` with the `Shifts` table

```
from datetime import datetime
query = session.query(Exam).filter(Exam.START_SHIFTED < datetime.now())

print query
# SELECT ...
# FROM [database].[dbo].[exam]
# WHERE dateadd(day, %(dateadd_1)s, [database].[dbo].[exam].[BEGIN_DTTM]) < $(dateadd_2)s
```

But when I try to run the query I get the following error:

```
query.count()
```

> TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined

I feel like I must be missing something simple here. I essentially just want the shifted date to behave just like the builtin support for `datetime` objects. Should I be using a `column_property` of something other than an `AssociationProxy` for defining `Exam.DATE_ADD`?

For what it's worth, my database engine is SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this, I ended up creating a version of the `types.DateTime` type that has overloaded [`bind_expression`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_api.html#sqlalchemy.types.TypeEngine.bind_expression) and [`column_expression`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_api.html#sqlalchemy.types.TypeEngine.column_expression) methods which apply the date shift. Additionally, I had to create a custom constructor which accepts the column which contains the date shift as an input and this is then stored for use in the `column_expression` and `bind_expression` methods.

This custom type will apply the shift to "decode" values received from the database and subtract the shift when performing any sort of filtering to make sure that the shifts are applied consistently.

```
from sqlalchemy import types, func, text

class ShiftedDateTime(types.TypeDecorator):

    impl = types.DateTime

    def __init__(self, column, *args, **kwargs):
        self.offset = column
        super(ShiftedDateTime, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def bind_expression(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return None

        return func.dateadd(text('DAY'), self.offset, value)

    def column_expression(self, col):
        return func.dateadd(text('DAY'), -self.offset, col)

class Shifts(Base):
    PT_ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    # Date shift in days (stored as an integer)
    DATE_ADD = Column(Integer)


class Exam(Base):

    PT_ID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Shifts.PT_ID))

    # Shifted start time
    START_DTTM = Column(ShiftedDateTime(Shifts.DATE_ADD))

    shiftlink = relationship(Shifts)
```

The only downside with this approach is that an explicit `JOIN` has to be performed for any query since the new type requires the `DATE_ADD` column. This is obviously necessary, but it would be nice if an implicit join could be performed.

```
session.query(Exam).join(Shifts).filter(Exam.START_DTTM < datetime.now())
```